# Angular ES6 Controller Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I would like to create an object with the result of two API calls and bind it to the scope. So far I have

```
export class MainController {
  constructor ($http) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$http = $http;
    this.getUsers();
    this.getPlayers();
  };

  getUsers() {
    this.$http.get('/api/users').then((resp) => {
      this.users = resp.data;
    })
  };

  getPlayers() {
    this.$http.get('/api/players').then((resp) => {
      this.players = resp.data;
    })
  };

}
```

I can now access users and players in the view by doing `main.players` and `main.users`. I'm getting very confused with the scope though. How can I wait for both promises to resolve and then bind a variable to the scope?

I tried `$q.all()` but I can't access `self.users` or `self.players` even if I set `var self = this;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is either using `resolve` on `ngRoute` to load the users before the route is loaded or use `$q.all` to wait until everything is loaded and hold view rendering:

```
export class MainController {
  constructor ($http, $q) {
    'ngInject';

    this.$http = $http;

    this.isDone = false;

    $q.all([this.getUsers(), this.getPlayers()]).then(() => this.isDone = true);
  };

  ...   
}
```

and then use `ng-if="myCtrl.isDone"` on the view side.

Comment: in the callback from `$q.all`, how can I access `players` and `users`? Should I be able to access `this.players` and `this.users`?

Comment: yes of course. You can even pass them as another argument in your callback `(responses) => { this.isDone = true; console.log(responses) }`